# Obtener orientacion actual en grados de la brujula del celular en android

Tags: android

Necesito obtener la orientacion que tiene la brujula del celular con android, seria conocer cuantos grados respeto al norte digamos, para luego orientar un google maps segun esos grados

Comment: Que has tratado de esto, tienes algún código?

Comment: Relativo a la pregunta no tengo codigo ninguno es decir a obtener la orientacion de la brujula en grados, no tengo idea de como hacerlo ni si se pueda hacer que imagino que si.